# Rails + FactoryGirl: What is the "evaluator" in after(:create) do |something, evaluator|?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been using FactoryGirl for a while now, but still don't know what evaluator means in the after create hook:

```
factory :products_color_with_variants do
  after(:create) do |pc, evaluator|
    pc.variants << FactoryGirl.create(:variant)
  end
end
```

I've only been using the first argument to the block, which is always just the object that was created. What does evaluator do and what can I use it for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes) can help you.  You can access transient attributes from it